# Regex for pattern [xx_- ].[xx_- ] C#

Tags: c#, regex

Hello im trying to write a regular expression for the pattern:
[anything].[anything]

so the pattern needs to start with a square brace, then can have anything comprised of (a-z digits, underscores, spaces and dashes) followed by a closing square brace followed by a dot followed by another set of square brace with anything in it.

this is what i have so far:

```
(\\[)((?:[a-z][a-z]+)).*?(\\])(\\.)(\\[)((?:[a-z][a-z]+)).*?(\\])
```

which works for [something].[anything]
but also works for [something].[any   <--should not match (must end with square brace)
also works for [something].   <-- should not match

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Edit:

```
 string pattern = @"\[[^\]]*\]\.\[[^\]]*\]";
 foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(haystack, pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline |RegexOptions.Multiline))
{ 
    do some stuff
}
```

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ will help

Comment: What about `[any[anything].[anything]` do you want it to match `[any[anything].[anything]`, `[anything].[anything]`, both, or neither?

Comment: Neither, only [anything].[anything]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get

```
\[[a-z0-9\s_-]*\]\.\[[a-z0-9\s_-]*\]
```

Seems to work ok for everything I've tried though I'm SURE there will be some exception, such is the beast that is regex!

Edit:

I'd probably use this as it doesn't match across line breaks and is less greedy (greediness will cause it to span multiple items which is undesirable)

```
\[[a-zA-Z0-9 -_]*?\]\.\[[a-zA-Z0-9 -_]*?\]
```

http://regexr.com?37fvh

Comment: Probably too greedy though - you might want to check it with multiple captures on the same line and adjust the greediness accordingly

Comment: This will also match with line breaks in between which is probably not what you want so use an actual space instead of \s

Comment: The `*?` quantifiers are meaningless, use `*`

Comment: Not sure what regex flavour you are on about but since this is C# regex, the *? specifies a lazy match for zero or more of the preceding. * denotes a greedy match and will match as many characters as possible, thus will match `[hello].[world]abc[hello].[world]` as a single match, which is not what the OP wants. The ? makes the * lazy so will match as few characters as possible. How does this mean they are meaningless? Why is your comment upvoted when it's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regexp to avoid [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html):

```
@"\[[^\]]*\]\.\[[^\]]*\]"
```

The expression consists of two identical subexpressions separated by a dot `\.` Subexpressions are composed like this:

- `\[` - An opening square bracket,
- `[^\]]*` - A sequence of any characters other than the closing square bracket,
- `\]` - A closing square bracket.

Comment: This looks about right. Note, for explanations http://regex101.com does a fairly good job.

Comment: Depends if any character is permissible - the list says a-z/underscores/spaces but not @ signs or plusses. Might just be clarification needed in the question

Comment: @user1336827: Then you are doing it wrong. It works fine: http://regex101.com/r/jO9uX4

Comment: @user1336827 That is very strange - it shouldn't, because the closing square bracket is part of the regex. Could you show your C# code around the regex?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You can avoid escaping in this case. `\[[^]]*]\.\[[^]]*]`

Comment: @hwnd That's certainly true. However, I think that adding an escape here isn't too bad, because `[^]` part looks a little suspicious (despite being 100% correct). I would agree that the expression is not too readable either way, though.

Comment: @user1336827 Your code works as expected for me - here is a [link](http://ideone.com/Ito30l).

Comment: hmm, I will have another look, this answer certainly is the cleanest.

Comment: I've added specific characters to capture in between the brackets in mine - but if you don't mind what you are capturing (not bothered about @ signs, +, commas, punctuation etc) then use this one

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
\[.*\]\.\[.*\]
```

#### [Example](http://regexr.com?37fv5)

Update to address greedy concerns:

```
\[[^\[]*].\[[^\]]*\]
```

#### [Example 2](http://regexr.com?37fvb)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your regex to match the end of a string you can use the '$' sign.

For example:

```
.*\]$
```

Would match anything that ends with an ].